I want to activate USB Debugging on my phone using ADB but my device does not appear with the command 'adb devices'
My phone broke and i can't see the screen and the touch is also gone for good.
I want to activate USB debugging on it so i can recover my things using my pc.
I decided to activate the debugging using 'ADB', i installed it but when i typed the command 'adb devices' my phone wasn't on the list of devices and i even checked if the usb was properly connected but it was. No ideia what i need to do, please help me.
My phone is a j5 pro, just in case it helps.
Thank you!

I am afraid, without using the screen, you won't succeed. Solely from a secrurity perspective this would be terrible. Imagine someone stealing your phone and beeing able to get all data. Maybe take another look on how to activate usb debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

You need to perform several actions on-device: activate developer menu, enable adb and finally when there is an adb connection authorize the computer by clicking a button on the screen of the phone. Anyway Stackoverflwo is the wrong place for such questions as it is unrelated to development: Check the existent question on broken scree here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen
